# Issue with LangChain and OpenAI - Unstoppable UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: openai-api, codespaces

I've been scouring the web for hours and can't seem to fix this, even when I manually re-encode the text.txt as utf-8 or change its contents. My code is super simple. Running it in codespaces using langchain and openai:

---

```
from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator
import os
import openai

api_key = os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY']
openai.api_key=api_key

loader = TextLoader('test.txt')
index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders([loader])

query = "What do whales like to eat?"
index.query_with_sources(query)
```

---

It was working yesterday. Today, with no change, it's throwing me this error. No matter what I do, how I change the text contents, how I reincode prior, this VectorstoreIndexCreator is throwing me this unicode error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

--

File "/home/codespace/.python/current/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1255, in putheader

```
values[i] = one_value.encode('latin-1')

UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2018' in position 7: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with unicodeEncodeError. Fixed it by setting the encoding with:

```
loader = TextLoader('test.txt', encoding='utf8')
```

You may need to choose the appropriate encoding value depending on the file type.